# Should one write short or long job application

Tags: job-search

In my country there is a web service for unemployed where one can write at most 4000 characters + include a CV. Should I use almost all of the 4000 letters to introduce myself or is a short introduction sometimes better? The service is not aimed for any particular job but it has about 11000 open jobs.

Comment: Write short and concise. People tend to be put off by long amounts of text. CV should do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard TL;DR;? Huge amounts of text are usually being skipped over. However, since you are in the position of being unemployed (for whatever reason), it does not hurt to really work on a short and concise text that is not the generic "blah blah". Write what you want to do, how you are keeping busy and how you would be of interest to a potential employer. Working on an introduction of oneself is difficult because lot's of people identify themselves by their jobs, but given time and enough iterations of the introductory text you will feel that the text flows, is right to the point (i.e. not too wordy) and that it clearly states what you can and want to do.